# Bower not working

Tags: macos, git, github, version-control, bower

I am using mac and I have some issue with bower. It will not download any git repository by it shorten name but it will if I provide a full path.

For example this call:

```
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
```

Will return multiple times:

```
bower retry         Download of https://github.com/PolymerLabs/marked-element/archive/0.3.3.tar.gz failed with ECONNRESET, trying with git..
```

But when I try to run this:

```
bower install --save https://github.com/Polymer/marked-element.git
```

Every thing works fine.

I have tried this with multiple repositories, so the polymer project is only an example.

What is wrong with my bower?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this github issue. But what helped me is just to make sure that my proxy settings in  `.bowerrc` file are correct. In my case I've just deleted al things that related to proxy settings.